# R - Applying a function to each row of a dataframe, arguments to function are values from each row

Tags: r

I would like to take values from certain columns at each row of a dataframe and use them as arguments to a function to produce a vector of predicted values (one for each row).

See function below:

```
predicted_value_generator <- function(theta, tau_host, tau_targ, rho, pop_host, pop_targ, distance, R0){
return(theta * R0 * (pop_host^tau_host) * (pop_targ^tau_targ) * distance^(-rho))
}
```

Dataframes:

```
> pop_dist_data

            X time_to_spread host_city_pop target_city_pop    distance      host_city_outgoing_flights target_city_incoming_flights flights_between      Reproduction_number_R0  
4           3              2        198100          622104  460.819668                            9158                        93861               6                       1.365
5           4              2        198100          622104  460.819668                            9158                        93861               6                       1.300
6           5              1        198100          622104  460.819668                            9158                        93861               6                       1.300
7           6              2        198100          622104  460.819668                            9158                        93861               6                       1.300
8           7              1        198100          622104  460.819668                            9158                        93861               6                       1.300

> fit_data
  X     theta1     tau_host  tau_targ        rho
1 0 0.05447868 3.288922e-09 0.1491428 0.00820936
```

Current approach:

```
pred_vals <- apply(pop_dist_data, 1, predicted_value_generator(fit_data[3], fit_data[4], fit_data[5], fit_data[6], pop_dist_data[,3], pop_dist_data[,4], pop_dist_data[,5], pop_dist_data[,9]))
```

Expected output is something along these lines:

```
> pred_vals
[1] 0.43 0.96 0.33 0.5 0.27
```

The `fit_data` arguments are constant regardless of row, however the `pop_dist_data` arguments should take that columns value at each particular row.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have updated the question. I hope this makes it clearer. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems here:

- `dat[:, j]` is not valid R syntax.  Use `dat[, j]`
- `R0` is nowhere defined
- `predicted_value_generator` is vectorized so we don't need `apply`
- `pop_dist_data` does not have 9 columns
- questions to SO should be shown in a reproducible manner so that one can simply copy and paste the code and data from the question.  This can be done by showing the output of `dput(X)` for each input `X`.  I have done that in the Note at the end.

Assuming that the missing `R0` is defined, try binding the two data frames together and then just calling the function with the appropriate column names.

```
with(cbind(pop_dist_data, fit_data), 
       predicted_value_generator(theta1, tau_host, tau_targ, rho, 
                                 host_city_pop, target_city_pop, distance, R0))
```

### Note

The inputs in reproducible form:

```
pop_dist_data <-
structure(list(X = 3:7, time_to_spread = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L
), host_city_pop = c(198100L, 198100L, 198100L, 198100L, 198100L
), target_city_pop = c(622104L, 622104L, 622104L, 622104L, 622104L
), distance = c(460.819668, 460.819668, 460.819668, 460.819668, 
460.819668)), .Names = c("X", "time_to_spread", "host_city_pop", 
"target_city_pop", "distance"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("4", 
"5", "6", "7", "8"))

fit_data <- 
structure(list(X = 0L, theta1 = 0.05447868, tau_host = 3.288922e-09, 
    tau_targ = 0.1491428, rho = 0.00820936), .Names = c("X", 
"theta1", "tau_host", "tau_targ", "rho"), class = "data.frame", row.names = "1")
```

Comment: Thank you. I did not know about the `dput()` function. I will certainly use it in future.